# PHP PDO Update statements always returning 0 rows affected rowCount()

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, rowcount

I know this is a noob question, however for some reason my update statements are always returning a row count of 0 regardless of whether a single row or multiple rows have changed as a result of a query.

Using standard php and pdo prepared queries. Tested select statements and they have been working fine with returning the `rowCount` number. But updates not so much. Here is my code. Any insights would be great.

```
$sql = "UPDATE token SET tokenkey = ? WHERE token_id = 1";
$r = $this->database->databaseConnections['core']->prepare($sql);
$r->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = "123123";
$res = $r->execute(array($data));

echo $r->rowCount();
```

I have used the same code (but with `SELECT`) and it will produce a greater than 0 result. I change the data variable, it executes, I check in sql database, it has updated successfully. But still a row count of 0 despite I can see in phpmyadmin the updated row, and if I run the sql directly in phpmyadmin it comes back with 1 affected row. Confused.

I also checked for `PDO` errors and receiving none.

For more information my pdo database connectors are set up with the following config (ignoring the connection details themselves.

```
        $connection->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $connection->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $connection->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $connection->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Cheers,

Masbie

Comment: Why are there back slashes in your functions? `SELECT` should not produce *any* result because [`rowCount()` dooesn't work with `SELECT` statements.](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Comment: what is your `select` statement? I doubt your `update` statement

Comment: backslashes as I am building this within a different namespace

Comment: OK - I had a braincloud where that was concerned.

Comment: Select statement was SELECT * FROM token WHERE tokenkey=? and it produced a result of 1 as expected

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO - Delete statements are working fine????? This is a strange one. Working fine as in their produce a number for rowCount

Comment: Your WHERE clauses are different between your UPDATE query and your SELECT query.  What result do you get from `SELECT * FROM token WHERE token_id=1`?

Comment: The select was targeted at the variable change, to test that the change did stick int he database, so they always would produce a value of one.

Comment: Granted, just making sure there was a row to update.  You can't compare the two to each other if their WHERE clauses are different.

Comment: yes granted poor comparison, it was just doing a test to try and debug this issue

Comment: no one has ever come across rowCount not capturing update statement rows affected?

Answer (score -1):

After much searching. Had to let loose the frustrations, therefore uninstalled all trace of the XAMPP server running. Then just reinstalled it. Same install and version that I used before. And then reran the code. And, now it works. Looks like there was probably some corruption within the server base. 
Cheers